# HERE map not showing in Android Webview

Tags: android, webview, here-api

Recently, I tried to use HERE maps for my website.

I used the javascript version of HERE-API.
My code are identical with the tutorial from this link:
https://developer.here.com/tutorials/add-a-custom-marker-to-an-interactive-web-map/

With addition of my api-key, I can see it works on my website.

But, on my Android Webview is shows nothing when I arrived at the same page.
I already follow the instructions here and applied it to my Android code:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/embedded-editor/dev_guide/topics/add-as-app-component.html

Is there something I missing ?

All dangerous permissions are already covered by runtime permissions in Android.
Also, I prefer to use the Javascript version for my website. The app simply mirroring it, so I won't be using the Android SDK version for this.

Any suggestion for this ?

Comment: Hi Lyn, would you please your code used in WebView Component ?

Comment: Hi, HERE Developer Support. 
Thank you for asking.

But since this is a fast-paced project I need to finish it soon.
So, in the end I switch to another map plugin.
The code related to HERE map is no more used.